# How to Set Price/Value of a Stellar Token

Tags: assets

I created a token called CTX for a Loyalty Program.

Currently it shows up in wallets as valued a $0.

[image]

The token will not be formally listed on any exchange. It is for a private community and is to have a FIXED "loyalty redemption value" of US$1.

How can I set the value of the token on the Stellar Decentralized Exchange blockchain database, to ***always be*** $1.00 , so that whoever receives the tokens will always see them represented in their wallet as having a unit value of 1.00 for each unit, instead of a value of $0?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.